# cant fix the position of the left container

Tags: html, css

I am not sure why the position for the circle and container for the left side can't fix like the right side. When I resize the screen, the circle of the right container can still remind in the middle of the line but the left side cant. Does anyone know what is the error?

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.375em;
  background-color: #D5D5D5;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.1875em;
}

.container2 {
  padding: 0.625em 2.5em;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 40%;
}

.container2::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.5625em;
  height: 1.5625em;
  right: -1.0625em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0.25em solid #86B5D0;
  top: 0.9375em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.left {
  left: 2.2%;
}

.right {
  left: 50%;
}

.right::after {
  left: -1em;
}

.left::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.375em;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 1.875em;
  border: medium solid #2D336A;
  border-width: 0.625em 0 0.625em 0.625em;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #2D336A;
}

.right::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.375em;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 1.875em;
  border: medium solid #2D336A;
  border-width: 0.625em 0.625em 0.625em 0;
  border-color: transparent #2D336A transparent transparent;
}

.content {
  padding: 1.25em 1.875em;
  background-color: #2D336A;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.375em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40%) {
  /* Place the timelime to the left */
  .timeline::after {
    left: 1.9375em;
  }
  /* Full-width containers */
  .container2 {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 4.375em;
    padding-right: 1.5625em;
  }
  /* Make sure that all arrows are pointing leftwards */
  .container2::before {
    left: 3.75em;
    border: medium solid white;
    border-width: 0.625em 0.625em 0.625em 0;
    border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
  }
  /* Make sure all circles are at the same spot */
  .left::after,
  .right::after {
    left: 0.9375em;
  }
  /* Make all right containers behave like the left ones */
  .right {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">

  <div class="container2 left">
    <div class="content">
      <font class="titleText1">1</font><br><br> ABC
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container2 right">
    <div class="content">
      <font class="titleText">2</font><br><br> ABC
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.container2` elements are positioned with `relative` so that they remain in a vertical flow. When you position the `.right` one with `left: 50%`, it shifts it exactly over the timeline: great!

Now you'd like to do the opposite for the `.left` one, which would be `right: 50%`. But that won't work as it's not positioned in `absolute`, so it will shift from its natural position within the page flow.

Fix this by setting it `float: right` so it starts from the far right and ends up spot-on the timeline. But it breaks the flow again.

So add `clear: both` to `.container2` to restore vertical flow and you're finally there.

One of the very rare instances where `float` can actually help!

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.375em;
  background-color: #D5D5D5;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.1875em;
}

.container2 {
  clear: both; /* Add this */
  padding: 0.625em 2.5em;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 40%;
}

.container2::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.5625em;
  height: 1.5625em;
  right: -1.0625em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0.25em solid #86B5D0;
  top: 0.9375em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.left {
  float: right; /* Add this */
  right: 50%;   /* Change this */
}

.right {
  left: 50%;
}

.right::after {
  left: -1em;
}

.left::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.375em;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 1.875em;
  border: medium solid #2D336A;
  border-width: 0.625em 0 0.625em 0.625em;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #2D336A;
}

.right::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.375em;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 1.875em;
  border: medium solid #2D336A;
  border-width: 0.625em 0.625em 0.625em 0;
  border-color: transparent #2D336A transparent transparent;
}

.content {
  padding: 1.25em 1.875em;
  background-color: #2D336A;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.375em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40%) {
  /* Place the timelime to the left */
  .timeline::after {
    left: 1.9375em;
  }
  /* Full-width containers */
  .container2 {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 4.375em;
    padding-right: 1.5625em;
  }
  /* Make sure that all arrows are pointing leftwards */
  .container2::before {
    left: 3.75em;
    border: medium solid white;
    border-width: 0.625em 0.625em 0.625em 0;
    border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
  }
  /* Make sure all circles are at the same spot */
  .left::after,
  .right::after {
    left: 0.9375em;
  }
  /* Make all right containers behave like the left ones */
  .right {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">

  <div class="container2 left">
    <div class="content">
      <font class="titleText1">1</font><br><br> ABC
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container2 right">
    <div class="content">
      <font class="titleText">2</font><br><br> ABC
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```